# How can I use directJoin with spark (scala)?

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to use directJoin with the partition keys. But when I run the engine, it doesn't use directJoin. I would like to understand if I am doing something wrong. Here is the code I used:

Configuring the settings:

```
val sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .set(
      s"spark.sql.extensions",
      "com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions"
    )
    .set(
      s"spark.sql.catalog.CassandraCommercial",
      "com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraCatalog"
    )
    .set(
      s"spark.sql.catalog.CassandraCommercial.spark.cassandra.connection.host",
      Settings.cassandraServerAddress
    )
    .set(
      s"spark.sql.catalog.CassandraCommercial.spark.cassandra.auth.username",
      Settings.cassandraUser
    )
    .set(
      s"spark.sql.catalog.CassandraCommercial.spark.cassandra.auth.password",
      Settings.cassandraPass
    )
    .set(
      s"spark.sql.catalog.CassandraCommercial.spark.cassandra.connection.port",
      Settings.cassandraPort
    )
```

I am using catalog because I intend to use databases on different clusters.

SparkSession:

```
  val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .config(sparkConf)
    .appName(Settings.appName)
    .getOrCreate()
```

I tried it both ways below:

This:

```
val parameterVOne= spark.read
    .table("CassandraCommercial.ky.parameters")
    .select(
      "id",
      "year",
      "code"
    )
```

And this:

```
val parameterVTwo= spark.read
    .cassandraFormat("parameters", "CassandraCommercial.ky")
    .load
    .select(
      "id",
      "year",
      "code"
    )
```

The first one, although spark did not use directjoin, it brings up data normally if I use show():

```
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Project [id#19, year#22, code#0]
   +- SortMergeJoin [id#19, year#22, code#0], [id#0, year#3, code#2, value#6], Inner, ((id#19 = id#0) AND (year#22 = year#3) AND (code#0 = code#2))
```

And second return this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {localhost:9042} :: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 2 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=307be82d): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s1|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)], Node(endPoint=localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=3ebc1052): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s1|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)]
```

Apparently this second way did not take the settings defined in the catalog, and is accessing localhost directly unlike the first way.

The dataframe that has the keys has only 7 rows, while the cassandra dataframe has approximately 2 million.

This is my bild.sbt:

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.15"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name                                        := "test-job",
    idePackagePrefix                            := Some("com.teste"),
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark"   %% "spark-sql"                               % "3.2.1",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark"   %% "spark-core"                              % "3.2.1",
    libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql"      % "postgresql"                              % "42.3.3",
    libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector"               % "3.1.0",
    libraryDependencies += "joda-time"           % "joda-time"                               % "2.10.14",
    libraryDependencies += "com.crealytics"     %% "spark-excel"                             % "3.2.1_0.16.5-pre2",
    libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark"  % "spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12" % "3.1.0"
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this behavior in some versions of Spark - unfortunately, the changes in the internals of Spark often break this functionality because it relies on the internal details.  So please provide more information on what version of Spark & Spark connector is used.

Regarding the second error, I suspect that direct join may not use Spark SQL properties, can you try to use `spark.cassandra.connection.host`, `spark.cassandra.auth.password`, and other [configuration parameters](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#cassandra-connection-parameters)?

P.S. I have a [long blog post on using DirectJoin](https://alexott.blogspot.com/2020/07/spark-effective-joins-with-cassandra.html), but it was tested on Spark 2.4.x (and maybe on 3.0, don't remember

Comment: I used spark version 3.2.1 and cassandra-connector version 3.1.0. Apparently spark version 3.2.1 is incompatible with cassandra-connector version 3.1.0. I changed the spark version to 3.1.3 and it worked correctly. I just needed to specify .option("directJoinSetting", "on") in the cassandra load. To solve the localhost problem I followed the article here: http://www.russellspitzer.com/2016/02/16/Multiple-Clusters-SparkSql-Cassandra/

Comment: great! You may not need to use `.option("directJoinSetting", "on")` explicitly, or at least set it to `auto` (if I remember correct name) - `on` will force always to use direct join, but if you have a lot of keys, more efficient would be to read the whole data

Comment: there is a PR to support 3.2.x: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/pull/1333

Comment: Do you have any estimate of when this will be stable for use?

Comment: When guys from DataStax will merge it. But it looks like it’s not in priority…